# IPN simulator Successful but does not Run database manipulation

Tags: php, database, curl, paypal, paypal-ipn

For some reason im having more trouble with this then I should... I have a IPN listner for Paypal and the IPN Simulator says successful each time and with different methods, but I can not get it to then manipulate the database based on a successful response.

Any ideas anyone?

```
<?php

//INCLUDE CONNECTION STRING
include('connect.php');

// STEP 1: read POST data

// Reading POSTed data directly from $_POST causes serialization issues with array data in the POST.
// Instead, read raw POST data from the input stream. 
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
$keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
if (count($keyval) == 2)
$myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the IPN message sent from PayPal and prepend 'cmd=_notify-validate'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
$get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}  
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
} else {
    $value = urlencode($value);
}
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}


// STEP 2: POST IPN data back to PayPal to validate

$ch = curl_init('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {

error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
curl_close($ch);
exit;
}
curl_close($ch);


// STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

if($payment_status=="Completed"){

    $selectuser = mssql_query("select statsmemberid from statsmembers where email='$payer_email'");

            if(mssql_num_rows($selectuser) != 0){
            $row = mssql_fetch_row($selectuser);
            $statsmemberid = $row[0];

            $getCredits = mssql_query("select creditsbought from statsmuplayers where statsmemberid='$statsmemberid'");

            $row = mssql_fetch_row($getCredits);
            $totalCredits = $row[0]+11;             

            $updatemu = mssql_query("update statsmuplayers set creditsbought='$totalCredits' where statsmemberid='$statsmemberid'");
            echo "Credits Applyed";
            }else{
                echo "Invalid Email";
            }




}


} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
// IPN invalid, log for manual investigation
echo "The response from IPN was: <b>" .$res ."</b>";
}
?>
```

Comment: As it's quite hard to read the echo'es here, as PayPal call the script in background, you should redirect any output to a file. Eg $f = fopen("log.txt", "a"); - then fwrite($f, "what I want to write/log..."); - This should help you debugging it. Also check Apache/NGINX logs for possible errors/warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you encapsulate all of this code into a few objects. That will really help you figure out where things are going wrong.

You want an object that handles the IPN communication with paypal (you don't need to write that from scratch here's the first PHP implementation I found in a google search https://github.com/dodev34/paypal-ipn-response-client)

Then you want a base object that handles your database connections.  And finally you want a statsmembers object that extends your database connection object and enforces your business logic. You might just lift some PHP ORM code like what you see here http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Quick_Start

That would allow you to test the update functionality separately from the actual paypal IPN communication.  The good news is at that point you don't have to rely on writing to system files for debugging like someone suggested in a comment above.

I don't see the specific error in your code just from a glance sorry, are you sure your passing the payer_email through paypal correctly?